# How does MySQL traverse a composite B-tree index for IN() AND IN() searches

Tags: mysql, indexing, b-tree, b-tree-index

I've been studying indexes and can't completely understand how MYSQL is capable of using indexes at all for statements like

```
IN() AND IN() ... AND IN()
```

The book I am reading suggests that when we have an index (`a`, `b`, ...) but user wants to search for `b` and we have a low cardinality in `a`, we can use a trick and simply add IN()

```
WHERE a IN ('x1', 'x2', ... 'all possible values go here') AND `b`>123
```

Let's say we have the following data

```
x1 1
x1 4
x1 456
x2 5
x3 1
x3 2
x3 3
x4 1234
```

How can it traverse this tree to satisfy the query above? Will it simply create all possible combinations for IN-s and will pretty much traverse tree for each of these queries?

```
WHERE `a`='x1' AND `b`>123
WHERE `a`='x2' AND `b`>123
...
```

therefore making this trick of limited usefulness because as number of IN-s increases, the number of all possible IN combinations increases dramatically and we'll have to run through the B-tree for each of these combinations? If the above is true, does this mean that there is some theoretical point where tricking an index with IN will get slower than not using index at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It merges the results from several passes. So yes, your assumption is correct. :)

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html

Before index merges, mysql could not satisfy such queries from an index.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct.

MySQL uses the same technology for this type of IN optimization that it uses when performing JOINs, and MySQL is capable of a high number of JOINs without having a noticeable effect on performance.

While the cost can eventually reach the point at which it becomes noticeable, it is still generally an advantage over not using an index at all.

Not using an index at all is only advantageous at the point in which you are returning a large percentage of the rows. MySQL is able to make the decision when to abandon the index.